# Get ordered outer points of a grouping of Hexagons

Tags: java, grid, mapping, polygon

I have a map with a hex-grid on it. I'm trying to construct "groupings" of Hexagons in order to create sub regions. I've got actually constructing the regions down, but the problem is the order in which each point of the 'edge polygon' is determined. What I'm looking for is an algorithm that, given a set of points, can (hopefully) construct the proper shape of the outer hexagons. What's important is the order of the points as when I pass that to [Dynmap](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/dynmap/) to construct a polygonal region, it's done by point order.

Shape-wise I assume it's a bit like convex hull, I believe, but wherein I don't want a new shape to be constructed with lesser points. As an example, below is what I'm getting and is wrong:

[image]

Below is the desired result, so to speak:
[image]

Thanks guys!

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you are doing.

Comment: do you have the code for that or is that something you drew in Paint Pro Shop?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be terribly efficient, but it's the first thing that comes to mind.

First, forget about the edges and just draw the red background color for every hexagon.

Now you only want to draw exterior edges.  That is, edges that are not adjacent to another hexagon. Create an Edge class with proper equals/hashcode (which is agnostic of the ordering of the points). For each hexagon, generate all its edges and collect them into a map which counts each edge. Now draw only the edges that have been counted once.

```
Map<Edge,Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

for (Hexagon hexagon : hexagons)
    for (Edge edge : edges(hexagon))
        counts.merge(edge, 1, (x,y) -> x+y);

counts.forEach((edge,count) -> { if (count == 1) draw(edge); });
```

There is probably a more efficient way, but this has the benefit of being simple, and it's probably fast enough for your use case.

Comment: The issue is that the order of operations is extremely important, because the order of the points is how the polygonal region is created. Edges doesn't get me all that much, because it's really the proper order of the vertices that's what I need.

Comment: You might want to clarify your question to explain why the order of the points is essential. In my mind, that doesn't seem necessary. If you know each of the hexagons, you have the region. It just remains to choose which edges to draw.

Comment: The choosing is the hard part. The code that I wrote does effectively the same as your, except by points instead of edges; so I'm getting the right points, in the end, but the order is incorrect (ie the first picture)

Comment: I don't think you are getting the correct points, though.  Consider the top left hexagon in your first picture.  If that hexagon is really part of the region, then you should not have chosen its two right points, as they are interior to the region. Conversely, if that hexagon is not part of the region, then you should not have chosen its two left points and top point. A similar argument can be made for the top / second from right hexagon. It seems like it is part of the region, but you've chosen all of its points instead of just the three on the exterior of the region.